# Не могу передать значения через Segue, да и открыть просто контроллер тоже

Tags: xcode, swift, swift4

Пытаюсь передать значения при клике по collection cell, но когда собираю проект и нажимаю на ячейку, приложение крашится с ошибкой

`reason: '-[UICollectionViewController loadView] instantiated view controller with identifier "UIViewController-hLg-LT-DtA" from storyboard "Main", but didn't get a UICollectionView.'`

Функция открытия другого контроллера в другом сториборде...
То что он пишет что не видит UICollectionView я хз как ему еще указать... тк получается что до нужного контроллера он доходит, а дальше не видит

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("Cell \(indexPath.row) selected")
        let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Catalog", bundle: nil)

        let catalogCVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CatalogCollectionViewController") as! CatalogCollectionViewController

        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(catalogCVC, animated: true)
    }
```

[image: Main Storyboard]
[image: Catalog Storyboard]

Comment: Тк я новичек в iOS прошу у вас помощи) У меня есть конечно предположение, что надо заново собрать контроллер... тк я копировал из других проектов и возможно где то что то не прописалось...

Comment: Добавьте больше кода, то что есть сейчас недостаточно

Comment: Добавил функцию и пару скриншотов

Comment: Сейчас нашел в одном из вопросов по похожей теме, человеку посоветовали убрать IBOutlet на UICollectionView. У меня они тоже есть и далее я использую datasource и delegate. Нужно ли убирать? если честно не сильно разобрался для чего нужен datasource и delegate, а просто в каком то уроке увидел

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Нашел решение...** Насколько я понял тут проблема была в иерархии... он находил первым **View** и понимал что это не то что нужно... В итоге переделал заново, сделав сразу **UiCollectionController** у которого нету **View и Safe Area** и все стало работать...

Конечно появились еще вопросы, но это уже я думаю в следующую тему...